# Create view without content

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a Home view (the principal page of the site) without any type of content like news. The problem is that when I create a view, I don't see any way to hide the content.

I have tried to put the number of items to 0, but this loads all contents. How can I create a home page without any content?

My Drupal version is 7

Comment: Question is, why you need to have views page in this case?? Views without content is possible when you have got exposed filters and checked options that required input data.

Comment: Is there another way to create a page without views?

Comment: Yes... You can use panels, nodes, hook_menu() and whatever you want.

Comment: So, it would get the structure of page.tpl.php but it will not show content.

Comment: The question makes no sense, why you would create a view if you don't want to show anything in it? I think you want to ask how to create a page in Drupal 7, I'm right?

Comment: How to create a page with not news content

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with Views just copy the `page.tpl.php` file of your theme to `page--front.tpl.php` and do whatever you want with it. In particular you can comment out the `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` and replace with any code you need.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I have one block in content. One idea is to copy the bloc code in the content part. I don't know if it is a good idea

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is. Try to edit the original post and provide all the possible details, describe the problem itself thoroughly instead of adding new details in the comments.